# Вместо какого значения строки может записываться значение "(MEMO)"?

Tags: sql, delphi, строки

Рассматриваемый функционал производит выгрузку данных из БД SQL Server. Результирующий набор записывается в текстовый файл. Сначала формируется строка к которой добавляются значения из выборки:
`strdb := strdb + '"' + Query.Fields[i].Text + '"';`

Когда просматривается сформированный файл видим следующее:
"10978";"";**(MEMO)**;1;2019;1;1;"4,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,4,4,5,4"...

1. Соединение с БД через BDE (да увы в 2020 это еще есть), сам проект на Delphi6.
2. Данная ситуация возникает только у одной клиентской базы из множества.
3. (MEMO) выходит только у 5 из 38 тестовых полей при записи. Единственное что общее у этих полей, наличие конструкции в выборке `RTRIM(REPLACE(Field3,''"'',''""''))`
4. Восстанавливал их бэкап и делал выгрузку, все нормально.
5. Выполняя запросы выборок у них на сервере получал корректные данные(БД клиента выше 2008).
6. Типы полей в БД: char. 
   Скажите пожалуйста откуда может взяться значение (MEMO)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это дефолтное значение у класса `TField` при приведении экземпляров этого класса к строке.

Среди полей, которые вы приводите к строке есть поле Memo (`TMemoField`, наследник `TBlobField`). В коде Delphi 7 определено:

```
procedure TBlobField.GetText(var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  Text := inherited GetAsString;
end;
```

В этом месте как раз и возвращается `(MEMO)`.

Я бы рекомендовал проверять типы полей и использовать функция `AsString`.

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения. Попробую с `AsString`. Проверки типов есть, но только определенных `if Query.Fields[i].ClassName='TStringField' then ... else if Query.Fields[i].ClassName='TDateTimeField' then ...` и в конце завершающий `else` на типы, которые не проверялись, и видимо сюда и ушла ветка с `TMemoField`. Удивляет, что этот тип был возвращен. Есть клиенты с теми же версиями SQL Server и программы, но отработка проходит корректно. От чего может зависеть?

Comment: Я с BDE не работал. Но думаю что от длины масимальной строки, например, если она меньше 2000 символов, то `TStringField`, иначе `TMemoField`.

Comment: Писать `ClassName='TStringField'` тоже плохо, правильнее `if Query.Fields[i] is TStringField`

Comment: Перешло по "наследству" так сказать, вот и маюсь. Спасибо. Больше 2000 выйти не могло, ибо сами поля в БД за размер Char(60) не выходят. Если только после отработки внутренних функций SQL которые описал, но это нонсенс.

Comment: проблема с типом оказалась прозаична, у BDE был неверно настроен тип серверного алиаса для соединения с БД. Для работы должен использоваться `type=MSSQL`, у клиента был выбран `type=SQL Server`. Так что если кто то столкнется еще копайте в этом направление.